# QR Code Reading App for Android 7.0

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to use my camera AND my saved images to read QR Codes - but I can't find an app for it :(.

The app I'm looking for should be able to do following:

- **Scan a QR Code from the camera image**
- **Scan a QR Code from a saved image and a selected area if it can't recognize it in a large image (e.g. the app QR Droid is not capable of it)**
- **Below 50MB**

Nice to have:
 - if the QR Code is a link: open it with the default browser
 - no advertising
 - free
 - not many additional functions
 - should work without unnecessary permissions

(I wonder why there is no QR-Code reader included in the default camera app...any ideas? Is it that hard to program?)

Comment: "I wonder why there is no QR-Code reader included" - frankly, I always wonder about that, too. Connecting to someone's guest wifi keeps becoming a chicken-and-egg problem like that.

Comment: You could check with [my list of Barcode reader apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_scanner). Usually those on F-Droid come completely without ads, so watch out for the F-Droid icon.

Answer (score 1):

**Privacy Friendly Barcode Scanner** comes close to your needs:

- [available on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.secuso.privacyFriendlyCodeScanner), which per se is a privacy friendly place
- [available on Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.secuso.privacyFriendlyCodeScanner) if you're afraid of "unknown sources"
- 2.3 MB
- only `CAMERA` permission
- but cannot scan from images

A second candidate would be **Obsqr QR Scanner:**

- [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=trikita.obsqr)
- [Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=trikita.obsqr)
- less than 1MB
- only `CAMERA`, and checking for/connecting to WiFi (for the chicken-and-egg O.R.Mapper mentioned: connecting to (guest) WiFi by scanning a QR code)
- again, not sure if it can read a code from images

For the ones I know that can read codes from images, I'm not sure whether they are ad-free

Comment: and which ones do you know that can read from images? Because the possibility of scanning from both the camera image AND image files is the most important for me - add free isn't thaaat important.

Comment: Ah, you hadn't pointed that out – I've restricted my answer to absolutely privacy-friendly candidates. Please check with my list (comment on your question): AFAIR *QR Droid* is capable of that. But wants a couple of more permissions.

Comment: I updated my question because it wasn't precise enough - QR Droid would've been fine but it can't recognize my QR Codes in big pictures and I don't want to crop those pictures beforehand every time. I want the app to have this functionality included if it can't find it automatically like QR Droid.